# Issue of convertHtml data missing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Have you guys faced the data loss after converted HTML to pdf? Here is my problem.

```
$scope.current.clause_note = '<ul><li>This is for testing <strong>TINTERIOR WORKS</strong></li></ul><p><br></p>'

$scope.current.clause_note = self.convertHtml($scope.current.clause_note);
```

The result remained the `TINTERIOR WORKS` `strong` parts and other tags were missing.
How to ensure all the contents convert to pdf without data loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) as shown below.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, $sce) {
 $scope.current = '<ul><li>This is for testing <strong>TINTERIOR WORKS</strong></li></ul><p><br></p>'

 $scope.current = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.current);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-bind-html="current"></div>
</div>
```